# Notepad++find/replace regex

Tags: regex-negation

Would like to know How I can tell note pad++ to remove and replace a line of code heres my example.

```
09615) + 9613:1 pushstring "assets/animals/d78b93a7450348defe627bb25cc13764.png"
09616) + 9614:1 pushstring "assets/animals/animal_penguin_undercover_icon.png"
09617) + 9615:1 pushstring "assets/animals/a41827a4e0a024750cea16b8be992a6a.png"
09618) + 9616:1 pushstring "assets/animals/pegacorn_party_full.swf"
09619) + 9617:1 pushstring "assets/animals/5fb70aee281a4014c09999d543adcd74.swf"
09620) + 9618:1 pushstring "assets/animals/sloth_sleuth_full.swf"
09621) + 9619:1 pushstring "assets/animals/b79532412ea2624fcb2bfe36ed461d01.swf"
```

Want to replace these lines etc. 09615) + 9613:1 pushstring with this

http://static-0.farmville.zgncdn.com/  beginning link to display images tried using the regex [0-9]+ but removed every number even out of hashed links just want to replace al

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Find dialog on the Replace tab, select the Regular Expression radio button at the bottom. Then in Find What, type in this:

```
^.* "
```

In Replace this, type in your url. Hit Replace All and you're gold.

You'll also want to do a Normal search and replace on the ending " to clean it up.

Comment: This worked awesome thank you so much I been manually picking lines out then adding url and getting my images that way.

Comment: K sorry bout all the questions but I know some php and coding but all self taught.The first question was answered great now I want to pull certain elements I'm using notepad++  so this for example are crops so want to organize.

Comment: This feels like it should be a different question. You'll probably get more responses on a new question with a nice example of what you've got and what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
find: [0-9]+\)\s\+\s[0-9]+:1\spushstring\s"([^"]+)"

replace: http://static-0.farmville.zgncdn.com/$1
```

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this should work. It's not tested, though.

Find:

```
^\d{5}\) \+ \d{4}:\d pushstring "(.*)"$
```

Replace:

```
http://static-0.farmville.zgncdn.com/\1
```